# How to convert plus (+) sign to "=+" with htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to convert every url which contains "+" to "=+"

for example that url:

```
http://www.bedavaemlaksitesi.com/mersinemlakrehberi210/index3.php?+
```

should be like this:

```
http://www.bedavaemlaksitesi.com/mersinemlakrehberi210/index3.php?=+
```

tried that and few other lines but doesn't work so far, i'm guessing it causes a loop or something.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)+([^/\.]+)?$ $1=+$2 [R]
```

Comment: Why would you want that? And the RewriteRule looks at the path, not just the query string. Your two capture groups are identical, only the first will match, and the `(..)+` wrapping is most useless. Use the `RewriteLog` to see why/how it fails.

Comment: Why ? Searching a workaround because of my web hosting companies restrictions. Better check this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8439606/655792

Comment: using that lines in htaccess file will prevent any further problems:

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|(.*)\.jpg|(.*)\.txt|images|robots|css|docs|cache)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?query=$1 [L]

instead of using only that lines :
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]

solutions in codeigniter's wiki is not working in some situations like when trying to use "+" and some other special chars.

http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Godaddy_Installaton_Tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just gonna give you  a literal answer for that specific example. Not sure if that will actually help you:

```
 RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING}  ^([+])$
 RewriteRule  /index3.php$  index3.php?=(%1)  [R,L]
```

You cannot repleace each `+` in the QS, as you do need a separate condition to match it first.

---

Also about your original rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)+([^/\.]+)?$ $1=+$2 [R]
```

Escaping the dot in the charclass is redundant, `[^/.]` suffices. And you need at least a separator between the two groups `/` to make sense. But you can't match the query_string there, that's handled separately from the current filepath.

See alsos: [ServerFault: Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as) -and- [HttpdWiki: Manipulating the Query String](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString)

Comment: it's not working, did you tested it ? or it's just my web server ?

Comment: No, did not bother to test that. Set up an `RewriteLog`